# Weblogic http session failover

Tags: weblogic

Currently I have the following setup:
  Hardware load balancer directing traffic to two physical servers each with 2 instances of weblogic running.

Works ok. I'd like to be able to shutdown one of the servers without dropping active sessions. Right now if I shutdown one of the physical servers any traffic that was going there gets bounced back to a login screen.

I'm looking for the simplest way of accomplishing this with the smallest performance hit.
Things I've considered so far:
1. See if I can somehow store the session information on the Load Balancer and through some Load Balancer magic have it notice a server is dead and try another one with the same session information (not sure this is possible)
2. Configure weblogic clustering.  Not sure what the performance hit would be. Im guessing this is what I'll end up with, but still fishing for alternatives.
3. ?

What I currently have is an overly designed DR solution (which was the requirement), but I'd like to move it more in the direction of HA (for the flexibility)

*edit* Also is it worthwhile to create 2 clusters and replicate the sessions between them (I was thinking one cluster per site, sites are close enough).  This would cover the event of one cluster failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting up a [JDBC Session Storage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webapp/sessions.html) pointing (of course) both instances to the same datasource without setting up a cluster, but I think the right approach would be setting up a Weblogic Cluster.

A nice thing about clustering Weblogic Servers is that - (from the link above, emphasis mine):

> Sessions can be shared across clustered WebLogic Servers. Note that session persistence is no longer a requirement in a WebLogic Cluster. Instead, **you can use in-memory replication of state.** For more information, see Using WebLogic Server Clusters.

Comment: Are there any advantages to using in-memory replication instead of jdbc persisted sessions? Other than performance, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

We've got a write up of this on our blog http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2012/10/basic-clustering-with-weblogic-12c-and.html which provides step by step instructions on setting up web session failover in a cluster.

Clusters are not heavyweight assuming you don't store huge amounts of data in the cluster as it will be replicated.